# Java RDP filter redirected printers by current user

Tags: java, rdp, printers

I'm launching this code on Remote Desktop Connection session to find printers:

```
public void findPrinters() {

       PrintService[] services = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();

       for (PrintService printService : services) {

            log.info("Found printer: {}", printService.getName());     

       } 

}
```

Code is launched as a windows service, system user.
When more than one user is logged in, I receive all printers connected, also from another users.
I would like to filter them by current user which use this process currently.

Comment: Please add more details, e.g. how are you running the app, are you running the application with local user rights or elevated rights?

Comment: @makozaki They said its running as a windows service, system user.  With the process running that way im not sure you can filter by user.  Or you could run the process under that specific user if that is an option.